# add html in json response

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am getting json from a sql query that looks like this:

```
    $zips[$i] = "{\"type\" : \"Feature\",\"properties\": { \"name\" : \"{$row["Name"]}\"},{$row["RegionCenterGeoJSON"]}}";
```

and where Name is it returns a zip code like:

```
    {"name" : "77002"} //with the rest of the response around it
```

in json. What I need to do is instead of just the zip code I would like something like this:

```
    {"name" : “<span id=’map_label’>77060</span>”
```

I need this because I'm using leaflet and mapquest and using this information to add things and adjust them dynamically...and be able to use jquery to do something like this:

```
   $(‘#map_label’).each(function() {
            $(this).css(‘font-size’, ‘20px’);
```

}

I've done this before but I had 1 json item and manually just changed the zip to what I needed, but now I would like to do it with hundreds of items in json in code. is there a way to do this in the php? I tried to just do this:

```
   {$row["<span id = 'map_label'>"'Name'"</span>" ]}
```

but with no luck

Comment: Are you getting any error? Also, could you post full json as you are sending it now (which doesn't work)?

Comment: Are you looking for `{"<span id='map_label'>" . $row["Name"] . "</span>"]}`? I probably don't have the quotes correct there. Also, it looks like you're generating json via string concatenation... don't do that, use an array and `json_encode()`.

Comment: Why not just use `$.each` to iterate over an array or object instead, and *then* add the markup on the clientside.

Comment: I have a working php that returns json that is correct and working, I just want to add the "span" around the zip code so I can do stuff with it in html/javascript. I should mention that I'm using this for GeoJson. the result I'm looking for is  {"name" : “<span id=’map_label’>77060</span>”} where 77060 is the zip code and I just add the HTML stuff around in but within the json